# PHP can't write to temporary files

Tags: php, file, permissions, centos, centos7

So I'm trying to set up [FileRun](http://filerun.com) on my CentOS 7 server and it needs to be able to write to and create temporary files, but it can't. I've tried commands, such as `sudo chown apache:apache -R /var/www/html` and `sudo chmod 0755 -R /var/www/html`, but that's made no difference. Please help... :/

Comment: Does writing to `/tmp` work? (it should be free for all)

Comment: @apokryfos The problem is that it needs to be accessible from HTTP, as well as PHP, meaning the visitor has it open whilst it's there. At least, I think that's how it's supposed to work.

Comment: It could be an issue with SELinux. I believe that is installed and enabled by default in CentOS. If so, apache likely wouldn't have permission to write to the folder(s).

Comment: @JonathanKuhn Nope, tried it. I disabled SELinux and rebooted, no difference.

Answer (score -1):

Could you please try the steps bellow?

```
cd /var/lib/php
chgrp apache * -R
```

Comment: Check FileRun configuration and see where exactly it is supposed to write those temporary files. Also be sure that httpd process is actually running as user apache and not as any other user.